# why do I get css error when markig lines as a comment

Tags: css

I have copied a css template and appended it to my personal css file. The copied css is the following (and some more underneath):

```css
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Pacifico');
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans+Condensed:300,700');

@mixin size($width, $height) {
  width: $width;
  height: $height;
}

@mixin position($top: auto, $left: auto, $bottom: auto, $right: auto) {
  position: absolute;
  top: $top;
  left: $left;
  bottom: $bottom;
  right: $right;
}

@mixin centered() {
  position: absolute;
  left: 50%;
  top: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}


*, 
*::before, 
*::after {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

*::before, 
*::after {
  content: '';
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
}
/*
body {
  background-color: #F3F4F5;
  background-image: radial-gradient(#F3F4F5 0, darken(#F3F4F5, 10%) 100%);
  min-height: 100vh;
  width: 100vw;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  font-family: 'Pacifico', cursive;
}*/

.title {  
  padding: 10px 20px;
  
  span {
    font-size: 20px;
    font-weight: bold;
    color: rgba(0,0,0,0.5);
  }
}
```

PROBLEM: As soon as put some of the upper lines into a comment, I receive an error in

```css
title {  
  padding: 10px 20px;
  
  span {                    <-- error colon expected
    font-size: 20px;        <-- error semi-colon expected
    font-weight: bold;      <-- error { expedted
    color: rgba(0,0,0,0.5); <-- error { expected
  }
}
```

You see `body` marked as a comment above. The same happens if I start the comment in the beginning or if I only mark the section above `body` as a comment. If nothing is marked as a comment, no error is highlighted. (using Eclipse as IDE).

Why is this so?!

Comment: Because you're nesting rules which isn't valid CSS. It may work is less, or sass or some other CSS preprocessor, but it's not valid  plain vanilla CSS

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @j08691 has already pointed out you are trying to use `SCSS` within a `CSS` file.

Since `SASS` is a transpiler for `CSS`. You may write your `CSS` rules inside a `*.scss` file so you can use both together. You will get a `*.css` file at the end. So you don't have to rewrite anything. All you need is a `SASS` compiler and rename your file to `*.scss`.

You can learn more about `SASS` (more commonly used) / or `LESS` here:
https://sass-lang.com
https://lesscss.org

Depending on what setup you are using there are `SASS` and `LESS` compilers out there for most common environments. You can look up [dart sass](https://www.npmjs.com/package/sass) for example it is a good choice for most projects.

If you just want to compile `SASS` to `CSS` you can install it with `npm` and then use the [sass watch](https://sass-lang.com/guide) command.

Comment: Thanks. Not that I understand much of this but I take as a message that this is no plain css, which is why much of this looks unfamiliar to me (I only know the very basic css). So I will rewrite what I need from it as plain css.

Comment: SASS or LESS is quite cool. It allows you to work with variables, mixins, re-usable functions, etc. You can nest the rules so you don't have to repeat yourself as much. You can lookup BEM if you are interested. For SASS/CSS convertion there is a tool called [sassmeister](https://www.sassmeister.com)